# Show formula field image in Visualforce Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, formula-field, document, image-formula

Image is showing up in internal visualforce page but not showing up in external visualforce site page.I have stored image in document and made it externally available and document folder is accessible to all users.
Also provided View All access to Document object under site profile settings.
Here is the image formula field.

```
IF( ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Up"), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015t00000004k4D", "Green"), 
IF ( ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Down"), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015t00000004k4N", "Red"), 
IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015t00000004p4I", "Yellow")))
```

Here is the part of visualforce page

```
    <apex:dataTable value="{!OutList}" var="o"  rows="11" styleClass="table" > 
         <apex:column value="{!o.Service__c}" headerValue="Service" headerClass="colHeadr"/>
         <apex:column value="{!o.Status__c}" headerValue="Status"  headerClass="colHeadr"/>
          <apex:column value="{!o.Image__c}" headerValue="Image"  headerClass="colHeadr"/>
     </apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: Alternative for Sites: put images in a static resource

Comment: @cropredy Thank you.It worked.Can you post this as Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get access to images in SITES, simply add the images into a zip file and save as a **public** static resource.  Reference the static resource using VF markup:

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.TestZip, 'images/Bluehills.jpg')}" width="50" height="50" />
```

Comment: Doesn't the `Static Resource` need to be public for this to work? I believe it will fail otherwise.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yep - thanks, I actually ran into this the other day and wondered for about an hour why I couldn't access the resources

Comment: Yeah that gotcha has caught me before too and it is *hard* to hunt down the reason if you don't know it already.